# Using import () in vue to import the component incorrectly

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2, babeljs

1. I'm using the babel-plugins-sync-dynamic -import package in the vue instance. What should I do?
2. I installed the babel-plugin-synch-dynamic -import package, and in the vue instance import the corresponding components, and he had the following error.

   `export default {
   name: 'App',
     created () {
       console.log(111)
       Promise.resolve(import('./Test.vue')).then(response => {
         console.log(response.default) // //Shouldn't you load a component dynamically?
       })
     }
   }`
3. [I wrote it like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWrre.png)[An error is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORi9k.png)

Comment: please paste the relevant code into your answer, just an image is not very helpful.

Comment: You should not need the `Promise.resolve` around the `import` expression